# DocumentDB: How to Update Partial Property Value

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have been struggling with this for a while. Here is my Document.

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "Scenario": "Welcome page",
  "Translations": [
    {
      "Language": "En",
      "Content": "Welcome!"
    },
    {
      "Language": "Fr",
      "Content": "Bienvenue!"
    }
  ],
  "LastModified": "2016-05-27T17:27:58.562-06:00",
  "ModifiedBy": "admin",
  "LastAccessed": "2016-06-13T10:27:58.562-06:00"
}
```

And here is my code to update the property (I've hard-coded the value to be modified here):

```
SqlQuerySpec query = new SqlQuerySpec()
{
    QueryText = "SELECT c.id, c.Scenario, t.Language, t.Content, c.LastModified, c.ModifiedBy, c.LastAccessed FROM MultiLanguage as c join t in c.Translations where c.id = @Id and t.Language = @Language",
    Parameters = new SqlParameterCollection() { new SqlParameter("@Id", Id), new SqlParameter("@Language", Language) }
};

Document doc = client.CreateDocumentQuery<Document>(
    collectionLink, query).AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault();

doc.SetPropertyValue("Content", "Welcome to Stackoverflow!");

Document updated = await client.ReplaceDocumentAsync(doc);
```

There are two parameters passed into this function. Id and Language. For example, I only want to update the property Content to `"Welcome to Stackoverflow!"` for `Id = "1"` and `Language="En"`. The thing is my code will remove the other `"Language": "Fr"`, `"Content": "Bienvenue!"` part and update my document to something like this:

```
{ 
    "id": "1",
    "Scenario": "Welcome page",
    "Language": "En",
    "Content": "Welcome to Stackoverflow!",
    "LastModified": "2016-05-27T17:27:58.562-06:00",
    "ModifiedBy": "admin",
    "LastAccessed": "2016-06-13T10:27:58.562-06:00"
}
```

But what I want is this:

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "Scenario": "Welcome page",
    "Translations": [
      {
        "Language": "En",
        "Content": "Welcome to Stackoverflow!"
      },
      {
        "Language": "Fr",
        "Content": "Bienvenue!"
      }
    ],
    "LastModified": "2016-05-27T17:27:58.562-06:00",
    "ModifiedBy": "admin",
    "LastAccessed": "2016-06-13T10:27:58.562-06:00"
}
```

So how can I only update partial property of the document without messing up other properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DocumentDB has no update in place. You have to read the doc, update it client side, and then re-save it over the top of the old one. Alternatively, you could denormalize your list of translations into separate documents with "foreign keys" back to the Scenario it relates to.

Comment: No, the example is exactly what I want. I want to update the English Content without affecting French property. In my code, I read the document, but couldn't update the English Content from client side because I have no idea how to only update English content inside the line <br/>"doc.SetPropertyValue("Content", "Welcome to Stackoverflow!");"<br/> Is that even possible in DocumentDB to only update one of the child properties?

Comment: Nope, replace or insert entire documents.

Comment: Yea, after some research, I realized it's not possible to update partial property. I't fine with me that I have to replace the whole document. But my issue is how to update one of the child property "Content": "Welcome!" and not affecting another one "Content": "Bienvenue!". The only way I find to update document property is to use "SetPropertyValue". That my problem: I have two Content properties. Is there a way to do something like SetPropertyValue("Content", "Welcome to Stackoverflow!").Where(Language = "En")? Thanks!

Comment: I use node.js for my NoSQL solutions not .NET. In JavaScript, I would pluck the array out with `a = doc.Translations`. Then I would use underscore's findIndex function `i = _.findIndex(a, {Language: 'En'})`. Then I would update it `doc.Translations[i].Content = 'Welcome to Stackoverflow!'`. I suspect something similar would work in your environment.

Comment: Thanks! This really helps!